# gdal2tiles generates small picture inside 256x256 tile

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, tiles, gdal2tiles

I've used gdal2tiles for generating tiles in number of different polar projections and always experienced the same problem — strange small picture inside normal 256x256 png with the rest of space transparent.
I'm using `-p raster` option.

That's how one particular tile looks like http://grab.by/uNHw

And here is the whole map view.

[image: how whole map with such tile looks like]

Looking for suggestions. Gladly will switch to other utility/program that can generate tiles properly in non-mercator projections.

Source geotiff I use are arctic and antarctic maps:

- http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/bathymetry/arctic/ibcaoversion3.html
- http://www.ibcso.org/data.html

Sample command I use: `gdal2tiles.py -z 3 -p raster ibcso_background_hq.tif`

Comment: Can you make a simple example, or at least give more details on the kind/s of source image and the actual commands used? Are you transforming somehow from the source because afaik that is not going to work in a single step

Comment: @mdsumner yes, sure, added two links to geotiff sources, and wrote sample command i use

Comment: This works if I do this, with no -z argument: python gdal2tiles.py -p raster ibcso_background_hq.
tif ibcsoraster  I can maybe have a closer look later, but it might be something to do with how the levels interact, but otherwise def a bug in the script.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why, but gdal2tiles does not seem to like a combination of -z and -p raster.

So I used `call gdal2tiles.bat -p raster ibcso_background_hq.tif`

and got the right picture in all zoom levels:

[image]

Comment: WOW, I would not have thought of this as the source of the problem. Can't even tell you how many hours I spent troubleshooting the issue!