# GDAL2Tiles crash

Tags: python, gdal, gdal2tiles

GDAL2Tiles seems to crash after generating tiles and no google viewers are generated, but only openlayers.

This is the code I run:

```
os.system("gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs EPSG:4326" + ground_control_points(input_file,Lon_max_min,Lat_max_min) + " " + input_file + " " + med_file)
os.system('gdalwarp -of VRT -t_srs EPSG:4326 ' + med_file + " " + output_file)
os.system('python "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal2tiles.py" -p geodetic -k -z "6-10" ' + output_file + " " + output_dir)
```

And what is printed in console:

Generating Base Tiles:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
Generating Overview Tiles:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

And these are the files created in the output folder:
[image]

If I run the following line, with verbose, this is what I get:

```
os.system('python "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal2tiles.py" -p geodetic -k -z "5" -v ' + output_file + " " + output_dir)
```

[Verbose's output](http://pastebin.com/nju06y81)

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

When specifying the profile with the -p flag the only option that creates the google viewer (googlemaps.html) is the mercator option.  The image below illustrates the resulting files and folders after running gdal2tiles 3 times on a small test image (image_4326.tif) by specifing -p mercator, -p geodetic and -p raster options respectively.

As in:

1. python "C:\program Files\GDAL\gdal2tiles.py" -p mercator image_4326.tif tilesMercator
2. python "C:\program Files\GDAL\gdal2tiles.py" -p geodetic image_4326.tif tilesGeodetic
3. python "C:\program Files\GDAL\gdal2tiles.py" -p raster image_4326.tif tilesRaster

[image: Side by side comparison of outputs from -p Option]

I also experimented specifing the -w flag using "all" and "google" as viewer options but this still does not result in creating the google viewer file googlemaps.html when either -p geodetic or -p raster is used.

Summary:  Change your -p option to mercator and the googlemaps.html file will be created.

Did some further testing and using -p geodetic and -z does not produce usable tiles.  This has been discussed here as well: [gdal2tiles generates small picture inside 256x256 tile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88305/gdal2tiles-generates-small-picture-inside-256x256-tile)

Comment: Thanks Rick for your detailed answer, however if I remove -p or select -all... the python execution still crashes. I'm pretty sure the problem is not related to the code but with the environment...